# Mass upvoting is as bad as mass downvoting

Tags: discussion

I got +55 in a space of 2 minutes, (4 answers and 3 questions) - this will more than likely be reversed.

Please do not mass upvote, there is nothing nice about flouting the rules.

Comment: If it was going to be reversed, it most likely would have happened by now. The voting fraud script runs daily at 3:00 UTC. In my experience, if the votes aren't invalidated the first time, it's exceedingly rare for them to be invalidated later unless further serial voting occurs. So in all likelihood those upvotes count as "fair" this time. There are some possible mitigating factors which would lead to a series of quick votes not counting as serial voting, though the algorithm for detecting voting fraud isn't public so it's hard to say exactly what was relevant here.

Comment: Lately, it has been awful for me on this site, not going into details - but feel like my time and effort was for nothing to a degree.  This game-playing is just the last straw on an already very weakened camel's back.

Answer (score 1):

I think that mass upvoting is *worse* than mass downvoting, because people may suspect the beneficiary (but really the victim) of being behind it. If the person isn't well-known in the community, they may be suspected, and their reputation (no pun intended) could really be bad.

Of course, this doesn't matter in your case, because you clearly didn't do it (after all, how many people who have had their posts serially upvoted have talked about it on meta! :-)). But for someone else, it could be bad.

I totally agree with you, though - serial voting, whether down or up, is a really crappy thing to do.

I do think, though, that there's the possibility that someone saw your profile and liked some of your posts, and decided to upvote. This is okay if they just upvote one or two, but 7 is a bit much. It's odd, though, that they stopped at 7. I've never seen that from a serial upvoter before.

Comment: Either way, does not matter much as I won't be participating at all in this site for much longer.